# Is it possible to scan all available SSID on Arduino platform?

Tags: c, embedded, wifi, arduino

Is it possible to retrieve the list of available SSID's using WiShield library functionality? And join subsequently join one based on some logic (rather than hardcoding SSID name)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, sort of:

http://asynclabs.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=404